# How to debug "System.Net.WebException" in a C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error when trying to put a music file and let it play when the user clicks on a button

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

My Code:

```
protected void imgbtnSongNotes10_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer key = new SoundPlayer("http://localhost:63792/01AmYisrael.mp3/" + imgbtnSongNotes10.ID + ".mp3");
        key.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Have you try to debug your program? It is probably caused by the .mp3 file is not exists in the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

the mp3 url is not exists ,you can  request this url in your browser。
http://localhost:63792/01AmYisrael.mp3/" + imgbtnSongNotes10.ID + ".mp3